# My abstract has been accepted for oral presentation but there is no info in the preliminary programme?

Tags: graduate-school, conference, presentation

I am a graduate student and just had my first abstract accepted for an oral presentation at a conference. We have been notified by email about our acceptance. Wheb I checked the preliminary programme today I couldn't find my name in any session. Does that mean I can't attend the conference or have been removed from the presentation list? I am really nervous about it since this is my first time presenting at a conference.

Answer (score 3):

In my field, it's common that the preliminary program includes the plenaries and symposia (where the authors are chosen ahead of time), but not the research sessions (where the presentations are chosen from the abstracts submitted).  I suspect that's what's happening here, but it's fine to contact the organizers for clarification.

Comment: This is the most likely scenario. The final program should include more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact the organizers of the conference and ask for clarification. It's unlikely that they canceled your talk without notifying you, but there is a problem and only the organizing committee can figure out what actually happened.